# why does Electron "new Set([large iterable])" produce an empty set?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, electron

So a simple thing like an 80 element array passed to new Set() produces an equally large set

```
new Set(Array(80).fill(0).map(Number.call, Number))
Set {0, 1, 2, 3, 4…}
```

However when it is larger from any source not just this quick filler function

```
new Set(Array(5000).fill(0).map(Number.call, Number))
Set {}
```

An empty set is returned in Electron 1.4.15

Is there some limitation I can't find in the docs?

Comment: Have you looked at `.size`? Are you sure it isn't just refusing to render 5000 items since it could clog up your terminal?

Comment: I suppose you are correct, strange that it doesn't just give the ... like all other way too large things

Comment: Fair point! Not sure where that particular logic lives.